# Is it possible to prefill workflow comment template based on value of content item?

Tags: sitecore-client, pipelines, workflow, workbox, commands

In my content item, I have a field called "**MyField**." Additionally, the workflow comment has its own field called "**MyField**." I am wondering if it is feasible to automatically populate the field values in the workflow comment template based on the field value of the content item.

```
MyWorkflow
Draft
 -Move to Pre Publish(has comment template)
Pre Publish
 -Move to Publish(has comment template)
Publish
```

Now, when a user clicks on "**Move to Pre Publish**," I want to prefill the value of "**MyField**" with the corresponding value from the content item's field.

Is it possible to achieve this? Is there any pipeline I need to patch for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a custom action

I am not 100% sure if it would run before or after the comments dialog pops up... Validation actions run before, so guessing it would be fine.

I havent tested the code, but in theory it might do the job (or at least give you something to start with).

```
public class UpdateCommentAction
{
    public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
        ProcessorItem processorItem = args.ProcessorItem;
        if (processorItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Stage Item
        Item innerItem = processorItem.InnerItem;
        
        // GET THE VALUE OF YOUR FIELD HERE
        
        // Workflow Item (Content Item)
        Item workflowItem = args.DataItem;
        
        // UPDATE THE VALUE OF WORKFLOW ITEM
    }
}
```

Code above is based of some examples I found here:

https://jodosc.blog/2021/09/04/how-to-send-email-between-an-editor-and-an-approver-in-sitecore-workflow/

Comment: Thank you for the reply Dean. Action trigger after the comment dialog popup. It looks like this can be done by customizing item:workflow command which sitecore uses for comment dialog –